# Flask Error 302 on Redirect after Form Post

Tags: python-3.x, flask, post

In Flask, when redirecting to different routes after a form is submitted, an `Error Response 302 (VFS connection does not exist)` is thrown. The below is a small example of what I am dealing with, there are other redirects in other routes too that throw the exact same response. There is not anything odd about the code or the redirect, am I missing something? (I am using AWS Cloud9 by the way)

```
@app.route('/data/import-data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])    
def csv_import():
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        #fetch file, some logical tests, parse to pandas df and session data - this works all fine and well
        
        return redirect(url_for('map_fields')) #error occurs here
           
    return render_template('data-import-data.html')

@app.route('/data/import-data/map-fields', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def map_fields():
     
    #get data from session data
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        #continue to work with the session data
        
        return redirect(url_for('data_table'))
        
    return render_template('data-import-map-fields.html')
```

HTML for a form for the first route that redirects to another route

```
<form class="" action="/data/import-data" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <div class="position-relative form-group"><label for="exampleFile" class="">File</label>
      <input name="csvfile" type="file" class="form-control-file">
      <small class="form-text text-muted">Max. file size 1.5MB(Mega-Bytes). Accepted file type .csv only. </small>
      </div>
      <div class="position-relative row form-check">
        <button hrefname="csvuploadbutton" class="mb-2 mr-2 btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Proceed
        </button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @PGHE `POST /data/import-data HTTP/1.1" 302`. The page that pops up after posting is where it reads `VFS connection does not exist`, the URL on this page does read correctly `/data/import-data/map-fields`